"No python at D:\" when trying to install poetry
I'm trying to install poetry, but it keeps looking for python in my D drive which died yesterday... It says:
No Python at '"D:\pinokio\bin\miniconda\python.exe'

I know very little python, does anyone have a solution?
I tried looking in my environment variables to see if there was anything wrong, but everything was as it should be.

Try reinstalling Python

I think there might be smth wrong with the path string. 1) Usually you have miniconda/bin/python.exe so the executable is in bin folder. 2) your path string starts with double quotes symbol "

Several things I think of allthough you didn't tell much...
One thing is the path is incorrect. the error indicates the path is "D:\pinokio\bin\miniconda\python.exe, but the path probably is without the quotation mark
Other thing can be that you need to reinstall python, that's because you wrote that D: drive died, so you don't have this path.
Last thing I think of is that your environmental variable changed. Press right key on "my computer", choose properties -> Advenced -> environmental variables. there you shoud enter the right path to the path variable. You can look here how to change it

Ok got it working, I just installed poetry through pipx and now it works fine
